# vsphere-connect javascript library error while client login

Tags: javascript, vsphere

I am trying to execute the example provided in the link [here](https://github.com/bhoriuchi/vsphere-connect/wiki)

However I get the below error while executing the code:

```
connect.createClient({
        ^

TypeError: connect.createClient is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/stack/nodejs/vmware.js:4:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the library with latest version of VMWare VCenter. Used the latest version of the library 2.0.0-alpha and example code from here http://bhoriuchi.github.io/vsphere-connect/#/api/client.method

It worked fine.